# dialog displaying dialog boxes image configuration

Tags: linux, dialog, modal-dialog, whiptail

I am trying to use dialog on my Linux box. The output does not seem proper.
If you look at not the whole box outline is in black. Can you please what are some commonly used color settings.

I cannot use whiptail.[image: Dialog Output]

Comment: I think the black box is supposed to be a shadow, underneath the grey box. It looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

`dialog` by default draws a shadow to imitate a 3-dimensional view (see [screenshots](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog-figures.html)).  According to the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Common-Options), that is optional:

```
   --no-shadow
          Suppress shadows that would be drawn to the right and bottom  of
          each dialog box.
```